# Protect Against Committing without Adding

Tags: git

My normal workflow in Git is to make changes and then commit the entire directory without staging (`git commit . -m "My message"`). This works just fine in most cases, but sometimes I inadvertently commit before using `git add` to add new files. When this happens, I usually just amend the commit, but it's harder to fix if I've already pushed the commit and made more. I'd like to prevent it in the first place.

I think I want `git commit ...` fail if there are unadded files in my workspace and make me opt-in to committing without adding (perhaps with a flag). Can I do this with a pre-commit hook?

Comment: I usually do `git commit -a -s -m "Message"` for some WIP code.

Comment: @0andriy I don't think that adds new files to the commit

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. To add *new* files you need to call `git add path/to/new/file`.

Comment: @0andriy I think you misunderstood my original question. I've edited it to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: `$ git commit . -m "message"` => `On branch topic/mfld
nothing to commit, working tree clean` You have some strange issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list unstaged, new files with:

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

A git [commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for it this could look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` ]];
then
    echo "You have unadded files in your workspace";
    exit 1;
fi
```

To opt-out of the check for a single commit, use the `--no-verify` flag on the commit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to check for unstaged files.

You can list the unstaged, new files with:

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

Here's a [handy post](http://codeinthehole.com/tips/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/) on how to add your own commit hooks